# How to check that only 1 element in a set has changed in a dafny ensures?

Tags: set, dafny

How can I check that only 1 element in a set has changed in a dafny `ensures`?

Example:

```
method myMethod(myParameter: int)
  requires myParameter >= 0
  modifies mySet
  ensures ONLY_ONE_ELEMENT_IN_THE_SET_HAS_CHANGED
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that one element was removed and another was added, you need to provide them explicitly as (ghost) return variables and use the `old` keyword to reference the previous value of `mySet`

```
method myMethod(myParameter: int) returns (ghost removed: int, ghost added: int)
  requires myParameter >= 0
  modifies mySet
  ensures old(mySet) - {removed} + {added} == mySet
{
  ...
}
```